# Load empty webpage with Chrome, without using "about:blank"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, browser, google-chrome-extension

I is there a way to load a page/tab with Google Chrome, without using "about:blank" as the url?

I have the following code:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: 'about:blank'}, function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.tabId, {
    file: 'inject-into-blank-page.js',
    matchAboutBlank: true
  });
});
```

but the problem is I get this error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot
>   access "about:blank" at origin "null". Extension must have permission
>   to access the frame's origin, and matchAboutBlank must be true.
>
> ```
> at Object.callback (chrome-extension://omelijcoklpokoeobkpepoipjpbakoeo/background.js:170:19)
> ```

As you can see I tried adding `matchAboutBlank:true`, but that didn't change the error.

...As I said, I am looking to open a blank Chrome page, which probably doesn't load an HTTP url, and whereby I can still inject a script into the page somehow.

Comment: You can't inject into a blank page, matchAboutBlank runs the script in child about:blank iframes, it's not for the main URL. You'll have to open a html file within your extension package, and that html file should have `<script src=...`.

Comment: yeah I could do that - I guess chrome://extension uses file protocol, not http